# I want to list all the files in my Linux server which are older than Dec 31, 2014

Tags: files, find, timestamps

I want to list all the Linux files in a directory and sub directories which are older than 31 Dec 2014. Please help me out for this.

Answer (score 17):

`find . -type f ! -newermt "31 Dec 2014"`

find(1):

```
-newerXY reference
          Compares the timestamp of the current file with reference.   The
          reference  argument  is  normally the name of a file (and one of
          its timestamps is used for the comparison) but it may also be  a
          string  describing  an  absolute time.  X and Y are placeholders
          for other letters, and these letters select which time belonging
          to how reference is used for the comparison.

          a   The access time of the file reference
          B   The birth time of the file reference
          c   The inode status change time of reference
          m   The modification time of the file reference
          t   reference is interpreted directly as a time
```